# Linked List queue [pop function]

Tags: c, list, queue

I'm trying to make a function that pop an element from a queue

```
/**
 * This function extracts from the queue the patient with maximum priority
 * @param queue is the extraction point
 * @return the patient with maximum priority or a Patient type value with all the fields 0 if the queue is empty
 */

struct Patient priorityQueuePop(struct PriorityQueue *queue);
```

The struct PriorityQueue is this:

```
struct PriorityQueue{
    unsigned size;
    struct PriorityQueue *next;
    struct PriorityQueue *front;
    struct PriorityQueue *rear;
}
```

and the patient is this:

```
enum Gender {
    MALE = 'M',
    FEMALE = 'F'
};

struct Patient {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    unsigned char age;
    enum Gender gender;
};
```

I tried to make something like this:

```
struct Patient priorityQueuePop(struct PriorityQueue *queue){

struct Patient *item =(struct Patient*)malloc(sizeof(struct Patient));

    queue->front = queue->front->next;
    queue->size--;

return item;
}
```

but I get an error when I compile it:

`priorityQueue.c:72:2: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct Patient *’ but ‘struct Patient’ was expected`
      `return item;`

Can someone explain pleas how this should be done?
Thank you

Comment: And where is the question ?

Comment: Your structs don't seem right. The `PriorityQueue` struct contains the pointer to the head and tail in every node, and there is no relation between the `PriorityQueue` and `Patient` structs.

Comment: The error message is self-explainable: your `priorityQueuePop` function declares it returns a `struct Patient`, but you're returning `item` which has type `struct Patient *`.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a pointer on a data and the data itself ? If not, you might learn C basics first.

Comment: Should be `struct Patient* priorityQueuePop()`

Comment: @Morovaille if I make my Patient item I've got another error:
error: invalid initializer

Comment: @flama just return a pointer on `Patient` as say by sergej, it will compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have the correct signature for your pop function.

```
struct Patient priorityQueuePop(struct PriorityQueue *queue);
```

This says that the function `priorityQueuePop` should return a `struct Patient`. This is different from `struct Patient *`.

```
struct Patient a_patient;
struct Patient *a_pointer_to_a_patient;
```

How do you return a structure? You don't need to dynamically allocate it.

```
struct Patient
priorityQueuePop(struct PriorityQueue *queue)
{
    struct Patient patient;
    struct PriorityQueue *item;

    item = queue->front
    queue->front = queue->front->next;
    queue->size -= 1;
    if (queue->size == 0) {
        queue->front = queue->rear = queue->next = NULL;
    }
    item->front = item->rear = item->next = NULL;
    populatePatientFromItem(&patient, item);
    priorityQueueDestroy(item);

    return patient;
}
```

Please note that while it is theoretically correct to consider the *cdr* of a priority queue to also be a priority queue, it is overkill in this case, since it appears your interface is not defined in a way to take advantage of it.